# Code coverage report using gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: maven, gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci, jacoco

I need to see code coverage report for a java maven project in Gitlab.
According to [this](https://medium.com/@kaiwinter/javafx-and-code-coverage-on-gitlab-ci-29c690e03fd6), [this](https://blog.gojekengineering.com/code-coverage-from-failing-the-build-to-publishing-the-report-with-gitlab-pages-a1d9a6a414c0) and some other sources:

1. I added `jacoco` to the list of plugins in `pom.xml`.
2. Added pages job to my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
3. Added `Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%` to code coverage parsing in project setting.

but there isn't any coverage report or at least I can't see it. There is no coverage percentage or coverage report page.

Content of `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/site/jacoco/
pages:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - test
  script:
   - mkdir public
   - mv target/site/jacoco/index.html public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify
  only:
    - master
```

`jacoco` plugin in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My Project is a private project on `gitlab.com`.

Pipeline and its all 4 jobs passed successfully.

How can I see the coverage reports?

Comment: Recently I faced the same issue, I documented my solution here https://notes.jfsanchez.net/post/109-gitlab-coverage-from-jacoco-reports

Answer (score 46):

It seems you forgot to add the calls to `cat` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

You should have something like that:

```
script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
    - cat target/site/jacoco/index.html
```

That being said, I don't think this is the best way of doing this, as you need to pollute your output with raw HTML in order to retreive the desired coverage value.

I would recommend using the method described in this pull request instead: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/488

- Keep the jacoco parts in your `build.xml`
- Use this awk instruction to print the correct code coverage total:

  ```
  awk -F"," '{ instructions += $4 + $5; covered += $5 } END { print covered, "/", 
  instructions, "instructions covered"; print 100*covered/instructions, "% 
  covered" }' target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv
  ```
- Replace the Gitlab CI regexp with what the instruction returns: `\d+.\d+ \% covered`

Edit:

As of Gitlab 8.17, you can define the regexp directly inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#coverage).

It may seem superfluous, but if this regexp is now part of your repository history, you can change it alongside the other tools used to compute it.

Comment: if you use multi module project you can do `awk -F"," '{​ instructions += $4 + $5; covered += $5 }​ END {​ print 100*covered/instructions, "% tu covered" }​' \`find . -name "jacoco.csv"\``

Answer (score 18):

GitLab employee here.

If your administrator has GitLab pages set up, you can see the URL that your artifact deployed to by going (on your project) to `Settings` -> `Pages`.

There you should see:

**Congratulations! Your pages are served under:** `https://your-namespace.example.com/your-project`

Click on that link and you should be good to go! Also we are expanding support for HTML artifacts. [This issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34102) and it’s related issues talk about existing and upcoming features that may expand on what you’ve built here.

Comment: Thank you. I found pages and the link to coverage report html file. But this file contains only simple percentage of code coverage. Do you know how can I see coverage on code? I mean seeing covered code as green lines, uncovered codes as red lines or something like that?

Answer (score 16):

In addition to what @SKBo said I would like to add a small tweak.

Having

> cat target/site/jacoco/index.html

will pollute you build output making hard to read what is important.

I would suggest it to:

`cat your/path/to/jacoco/report/index.html | grep -o '<tfoot>.*</tfoot>'`

That will reduce the noise in a great manner

Comment: The link is now
`jacoco/report/html/index.html`

So, the final command would be `cat your/path/to/jacoco/report/html/index.html | grep -o '<tfoot>.*</tfoot>'`

Answer (score 9):

In order to display the basic Total Coverage Percentage all you need is:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
    - cat target/site/jacoco/index.html | grep -o 'Total[^%]*%'
  coverage: '/Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%/'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
    expire_in: 1 mos
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

and if you want to enable the Code Coverage Visualization feature:

```yaml
visualize_test_coverage:
  stage: visualize_test_coverage
  image: registry.gitlab.com/haynes/jacoco2cobertura:1.0.7
  script:
    - 'python /opt/cover2cover.py target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml src/main/java > target/site/cobertura.xml'
    - 'python /opt/source2filename.py target/site/cobertura.xml'
  needs: [ "test" ]
  dependencies:
    - test
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: target/site/cobertura.xml
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

for detailed information check the official Gitlab Docs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/test_coverage_visualization.html)

Comment: Hi @magiccrafter, my target folder is not getting jacoco folder automatically what should i do?

Answer (score 8):

I use this command in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
cat target/site/jacoco-merge/index.html | grep -o 'Total[^%]*%' | sed 's/<.*>/ /; s/Total/Jacoco Coverage Total:/'
```

This prints a nice string without mess and html tags:

```
Jacoco Coverage Total: 39%
```

and then you can use the regex mentioned in gitlabs documentation:

```
Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%
```

or you can use:

```
Jacoco Coverage Total: ([0-9]{1,3})%
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using this code:

```
image: maven:latest

sonarqube-check:
  script:
    - mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
    - cat target/site/jacoco/index.html | grep -o '.*'
  allow_failure: false
  coverage: "/Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to parse the HTML output, this short awk script extracts the percentage from the jococo.csv file.

```
#!/bin/sh

# This awk script calculates a code coverage %
# usage: pass the the jacoco.csv file as first argument

awk -F "," '
    {
      instructions += $4 + $5; covered += $5
    }
    END {
      print covered, "/", instructions, "instructions covered";
      printf "%.2f%% covered\n", covered / instructions * 100
    }' "$1"
```

Prints:

```
coverage.sh target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv 
369992 / 469172 instructions covered
78.86% covered
```

You should adjust the printf format to match your Gitlab coverage regex

Comment: Note that it's also possible to use a `#!/usr/bin/awk` shebang, but it's less portable due to some compatibility issues with different distros and versions of gawk.

Answer (score 1):

full CI example, based on previous answers, working for both unit & integration tests

```sh
test:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3.8-openjdk-17-slim
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify
      # jacoco code-coverage reporting
    - if [ -f target/site/jacoco/index.html ]; then awk -F"," '{ instructions += $4 + $5; covered += $5 } END { print 100*covered/instructions, "% covered" }' target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv; fi
    - if [ -f target/site/jacoco-it/index.html ]; then awk -F"," '{ instructions += $4 + $5; covered += $5 } END { print 100*covered/instructions, "% covered" }' target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.csv; fi
  coverage: '/([0-9.]*) % covered/'
```

Answer (score 0):

add a new job , exec script

```
awk -F"," '{ instructions += $4 + $5; covered += $5 } END { print int(100*covered/instructions), "% covered" }' target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv
```

GET THIS

74 % covered